# Does 'substring' work directly in an EJS file

Tags: node.js, ejs

```js
<%- include("partials/header"); -%>

<h1>Home</h1>
<p><%= startingContent %></p>

<% posts.forEach(function(post){ %>

<h1><%=post.title%></h1>
<p>
  <%=post.content.substring(0, 100) + " ..."%>
  <!-- This line's giving me an error, I dont know why -->
  <a href="/posts/<%=post._id%>">Read More</a>
</p>

<% }) %> <%- include("partials/footer"); -%>
```

Normally, it's supposed to reduce the number of characters to be displayed to a specific number(in this case 100).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's actually working, it can even be used on a declared variable in as JS file, the reason it wasn't working for me was because I mistakenly misspelt my 'content'.

```
const str = 'Mozilla';

console.log(str.substring(1, 3));
// Expected output: "oz"

console.log(str.substring(2));
// Expected output: "zilla"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%- include("partials/header") -%>

<h1>Home</h1>

<p><%= homeContent %></p>`enter code here`
<% posts.forEach(function(post) { %>  
  <h1><%= post.title %></h1>
  <% if (typeof post.content === 'string') { %>
    <p><%= post.content.substring(0, 100) + " ..." %></p>
  <% } else if (Array.isArray(post.content)) { %>
    <p><%= post.content[0].substring(0, 100) + " ..." %></p>
  <% } %>
<% }) %>

<%- include("partials/footer") -%>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.